# How to write Gstreamer-RS custom plugin with capability to update/overwrite extension header without allocation overhead in Rust?

Tags: rust, gstreamer

I am creating a custom plugin with `application/x-rtp` as sync and src. I want to add custom payload to the extension. My plugin definition is :

```
glib::wrapper! {
    pub struct CustomPlugin(ObjectSubclass<imp::CustomPlugin>) @extends gst_base::BaseTransform, gst::Element, gst::Object;
}
```

In `transform_ip`, I just want to add custom data to the extension.
As of current I have

```
fn transform_ip(&self, element: &Self::Type, buf: &mut gst::BufferRef) -> Result<gst::FlowSuccess, gst::FlowError> {
        let mut out_frame: BufferMap<Writable> = buf.map_writable().map_err(|_| {
            gst::element_error!(
                element,
                gst::CoreError::Failed,
                ["Failed to map input buffer readable"]
            );
            gst::FlowError::Error
        })?;
        let mut_buf: &mut Buffer;// = out_frame... 
        let mut rtp_buffer = RTPBuffer::from_buffer_writable(mut_buf).unwrap();
        rtp_buffer.add_extension_onebyte_header(1u8, &[1u8]).unwrap();
        Ok(gst::FlowSuccess::Ok)
    }
```

Line containing `let mut_buf: &mut Buffer;// = out_frame...`  needs to be fixed.
My questions are :

1. Am I going in the right direction. Do I need to use a different Base class. The current base class is `gst_base::BaseTransform`.
2. I am new to multimedia and Rust. Is there a good resource apart from [gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer). It is a good source but I find it difficult to follow. Though tutorial with Rust is fantastic with detailed explanations.

Comment: I was able to make buffer from BufferRef using `let mut new_buf = unsafe {gst::Buffer::from_glib_full(buf.as_mut_ptr())};` but then at end get error `(gst-launch-1.0:59163): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 17:24:08.834: gst_pad_push: assertion 'GST_IS_BUFFER (buffer)' failed.` Still stuck !!!

Answer (score 0):

[GStreamer Change to fix above issue](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer-rs/-/merge_requests/844)
Gstreamer team made a change to the interface and now `RTPBuffer::from_buffer_writable` accepts `&mut gst::BufferRef`, which we already have.
Final code looks like

```
fn transform_ip(&self, element: &Self::Type, buf: &mut gst::BufferRef) -> Result<gst::FlowSuccess, gst::FlowError> {
        let mut rtp_buffer = RTPBuffer::from_buffer_writable(&mut buf).unwrap();
        rtp_buffer.add_extension_onebyte_header(1u8, &[1u8]).unwrap();
        Ok(gst::FlowSuccess::Ok)
    }
```

And we have fix. Thanks, GStreamer team to resolving this fast.